# How to use printWhenExpression in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Can somebody tell me how to use the *`printWhenExpression`* of JasperReports?

Answer (score 21):

Do you have an error relative to boolean ?

Because you need to use Boolean instead of the primitive type.

So:

```
$F{mesure} != "PH"
($F{userfd4}).equals("1") ? true : false
```

would give `cannot cast from boolean to Boolean`.

```
( $F{mesure}.startsWith("PH") ? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE ) 
($F{userfd4}).equals("1") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

would be correct.

See also this [example](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=47713)

---

Update Nov 2015 (7 years later)

[Petter Friberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5292302/petter-friberg) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294989/how-to-use-printwhenexpression-in-jasperreports/294999?noredirect=1#comment55033358_294999):

> In [jasper report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports) 6.0 this is not need:
>   You can return either `boolean` or `Boolean` a simple expression like `$F{fieldName}.equals("hello")` will work.

---

You can see a demo of that command in [`demo/samples/tableofcontents/reports/TocPart.jrxml`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/89055a52f85c589ff08f0a72d0108ecf17a388e6/jasperreports/demo/samples/tableofcontents/reports/TocPart.jrxml#L61-L68)

```
<reportElement style="Sans_Bold" positionType="Float" x="50" y="0" width="100" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="db8b68c6-4430-4199-8967-3ab5c077cb56">
    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question. It does not explain how to use `printWhenExpression`. It only explains that the expression needs a boolean. While "this expression needs a boolean" is helpful, it does not exactly answer the "how to use" part.

Comment: I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.12.2 and still had to use the old way. It compiled and it was still printing, without giving any errors.

Comment: @g-otn So how did you use JasperReports `printWhenExpression` in your case?

Comment: @VonC , I used the way your answer suggested (before the update): `$F{somefield}.equals("something") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE`.

Answer (score 5):

The other poster has done a good job of explaining the technical details of how to use it, so I'll try and explain the circumstances in which one might find it useful.

Basically, it allows you to show or hide the contents of a cell based on a boolean expression. For example, you might want to show a person's name only if that person is over 18, then in the name field, using a printwhenexpression like:

```
$F{age} >= 18
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the static method "Boolean.valueOf(boolean b)".  It does exactly the same logic as "($F{mesure}.startsWith("PH") ? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE)" and good rule of thumb is don't recreate the wheel.

> Boolean.valueOf($F{mesure}.startsWith("PH"))
>
> Boolean.valueOf($F{userfd4}).equals("1"))

Answer (score 1):

$P{mesure}.equals("200") should work without any additional details. It will print if the condition is true