# Add group of text fields but show only one group field which has data in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two groups text fields.

1st group (Stock Code) is :

```
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S1_KL}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S2_JB}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S3_NB}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S4_SB}
```

2nd group (Asset Code) is :

```
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_A1_GOLONGAN}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_A2_BIDANG}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_A3_KELOMPOK}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_A4_SUBKELOMPOK}
$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_A5_SUBSUBKEL}
```

and I have field called Product :

```
 $F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_PRODUCT}
```

Each product has either Asset Code / Stock Code.
If a product has Asset Code, then Stock Code field is automatically blank, 
it works the other way around.

```
Code    || Product
----------------------
1-2-1-1 || Stock Goods
0-2-3-1 || Asset Goods
```

How can I make it automatically show each product with matching code?

Comment: for all the fields, check "Blank When Null" = true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for all the textfields in group add property "Blank When Null"(isBlankWhenNull="true")

**update: Added PrintWhenExpression**

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
<reportElement x="143" y="29" width="260" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S1_KL}!=null && $F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S2_JB}!=null && $F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S3_NB}!=null && $F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S4_SB}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
<box leftPadding="2"/>
<textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
    <font isBold="true"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S1_KL}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

or you can also use [print when expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294989/how-to-use-printwhenexpression-in-jasperreports)

Comment: In the field, I use $F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S1_KL}+"-"+$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S2_JB}+"-"+$F{VW_STOCKOPNAME_S3_NB} I checked Blank When Null, but it appears something like null-null-null, how can I fix it?

Comment: @SalmaSulthanah i have updated my answer with printWhenExpression , check if it works

Comment: @SalmaSulthanah Accept the answer if it has solved your problem